# Extended tsconfig.json cannot find type definition of scoped package in VSCode

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-declarations

**Problem:**

I'm using a scoped package (i.e. `@ews/ntlm-client`) that doesn't have built-in type definitions. I created custom type definitions locally in a main `tsconfig.json`, and then used an extended `tsconfig.json`. But VSCode complains the extended `tsconfig.json` cannot find the definitions for the scoped package.

**What I've Tried:**

I created a type definition and placed it in `<baseurl>\typedefs\@types\@ews\ntlm-client\index.d.ts`:

```js
declare module '@ewsjs/ntlm-client' {
    function createType1Message(workstation?: string, domain?: string): string;
    function decodeType2Message(wwwAuthenticate?: string | null): any;
    function createType3Message(type2msg: any, username?: string, password?: string, workstation?: string, domain?: string): string;
}
```

I added the type definitions folder to my `<baseurl>\tsconfig.json`. Do note I'm not running the `tsc` transpiler as I'm coding in JS, not TS:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "checkJs": true,

        "lib": ["ES2019"],
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "target": "ES2019",
        "noEmit": true,

        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typedefs/@types"]
    }
}
```

And then extended the tsconfig using `<baseurl>\a\b\tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

But I'm getting the following Visual Studio Code error in my `<baseurl>\a\b\tsconfig.json`:

[image]

Why is this happening? I also have type definitions for other modules in my custom @types folder, but they don't seem to throw the same error.

[image]

I also note that my main `<baseurl>\tsconfig.json` does not seem to have this error.

Comment: The `declare module 'm' {}` wrapper is incorrect. It doesn't do what you think it does. Remove it and export the declarations inside just as your would from a source file. Also, you should specify `"moduleResolution": "Node"`. You may need to make additional changes, but you will want to do as I suggested.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you elaborate? If I remove `declare module 'm' {}`, I'm geting `Could not find a declaration file for module 'm'` for ALL of my defined types, not just the scoped ones. `moduleResolution` is fine, I have `module: "CommonJS"`

Comment: When you use the clear module, you can't resolve it as a file. It has to be imported via the exact specifier.

Answer (score 2):

The definitions for Scoped Packages have a different file name convention:

> remove the prefix @, and change the forward slash to a double-underscore

E.g. The types for `@types/@babel/traverse` should be found in `@types/babel__traverse/index.d.ts`.